# ActionBarCompat Spinner not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I have an issue with an ActionBar spinner. I'm using ActionBarCompat. I've see the issue on Gingerbread, JB and KK.

Here's my activity:

```
public class WikiActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
    protected ArrayList<Project> mProjects;
    protected ArrayAdapter<Project> mAdapter;
    public int mCurrentProjectPosition;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initProjectsSpinner(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        L.d("item" + item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refreshProjectsList();
    }

    private void initProjectsSpinner(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mCurrentProjectPosition = -1;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mProjects = new ArrayList<Project>();
            mAdapter = new ProjectsSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.main_nav_item, mProjects);
        }
    }

    private void enableListNavigationMode() {
        L.d("current proj pos=" + mCurrentProjectPosition);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        ab.setListNavigationCallbacks(mAdapter, this);
        if (mCurrentProjectPosition >= 0) {
            ab.setSelectedNavigationItem(mCurrentProjectPosition);
        }
    }

    public void refreshProjectsList() {
        L.d("");
        if (mProjects != null && mProjects.size() > 0) {
            return;
        }
        L.d("");
        Project p = new Project();
        p.name = "test1";
        mProjects.add(p);
        p = new Project();
        p.name = "test2";
        mProjects.add(p);
        p = new Project();
        p.name = "test3";
        mProjects.add(p);
        p = new Project();
        p.name = "test4";
        mProjects.add(p);

        enableListNavigationMode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final int itemPosition, final long itemId) {
        L.d("position: " + itemPosition);
        if (mProjects == null || itemPosition < 0 || itemPosition > mProjects.size()) {
            return true;
        }

        mCurrentProjectPosition = itemPosition;
        Project currentProject = mProjects.get(mCurrentProjectPosition);
        L.d("currentProject=" + currentProject);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's the adapter. I agree it could be improved (with the use of a views holder for example), but it's not the problem here.

```
public class ProjectsSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Project> {
    ArrayList<Project> data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ProjectsSpinnerAdapter(final Context ctx, final int textViewResourceId, final ArrayList<Project> data) {
        super(ctx, textViewResourceId, data);
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_nav_item_in_actionbar, null);
        }
        final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main_nav_ab_item_text);
        if (text != null && data != null && position < data.size()) {
            text.setText(data.get(position).name);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_nav_item, null);
        }
        final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main_nav_item_text);
        final View image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.main_nav_item_icon);
        if (text != null && image != null) {
            text.setText(data.get(position).name);
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Project getItem(final int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So it's quite simple in fact. My code is way more complicated, but I could reduce it to this and it's still failing. It used to work perfectly with ABS, not that I switched to ActionBarCompat it's not working anymore.

When I touch the spinner in the action bar, nothing happens. It doesn't unfold. What's wrong?

Here's the log:

```
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:25 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::<init>() ---
Context: net.bicou.redmine.app.wiki.WikiActivity@431e35c0, textViewResourceId: 2130903113, data: []
--- WikiActivity.java:65 WikiActivity::refreshProjectsList() ---
--- WikiActivity.java:69 WikiActivity::refreshProjectsList() ---
--- WikiActivity.java:54 WikiActivity::enableListNavigationMode() ---
current proj pos=-1
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
--- WikiActivity.java:88 WikiActivity::onNavigationItemSelected() ---
position: 0
--- WikiActivity.java:95 WikiActivity::onNavigationItemSelected() ---
currentProject=Project { id: 0, name: test1, identifier: null }
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 0, convertView: null, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020261 android:id/action_bar_spinner}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 0, convertView: null, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020261 android:id/action_bar_spinner}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 1, convertView: android.widget.LinearLayout{42c86858 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 2, convertView: android.widget.LinearLayout{42c86858 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 3, convertView: android.widget.LinearLayout{42c86858 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 0, convertView: null, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020261 android:id/action_bar_spinner}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 0, convertView: null, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......ID 0,0-204,144 #1020261 android:id/action_bar_spinner}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 0, convertView: null, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......ID 0,0-204,144 #1020261 android:id/action_bar_spinner}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:66 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getCount() ---
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 0, convertView: null, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......ID 0,0-204,144 #1020261 android:id/action_bar_spinner}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 1, convertView: android.widget.LinearLayout{42d3a630 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......ID 0,0-20
er}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 2, convertView: android.widget.LinearLayout{42d3a630 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......ID 0,0-20
er}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:32 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getView() ---
position: 3, convertView: android.widget.LinearLayout{42d3a630 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, parent: android.widget.Spinner{43163858 VFED.... ......ID 0,0-20
er}
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
--- ProjectsSpinnerAdapter.java:78 ProjectsSpinnerAdapter::getItemId() ---
position: 0
```

Then I tapped the spinner multiple times. Nothing. Then I tapped the up button from the action bar:

```
--- WikiActivity.java:26 WikiActivity::onOptionsItemSelected() ---
itemandroid.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapperJB@432778d8
```

Really, nothing happens on that spinner. It's *dead*.

Comment: is your menu using something similar to this? yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

Comment: Yes it is, but I'm not talking about the `SearchView` here (which works properly, BTW).

Comment: Is `getDropDownView` method called? Can you step through it?

Comment: Thanks for your input @Szymon, I've updated the log so that every method of the adapter logs something when called. `getDropDownView` is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. It was because of my theme/styles.

Here's the app theme (the one the activity uses):

```
<item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/Theme.MyMine.DropDownNav</item>
<item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/Theme.MyMine.DropDownNav</item>
```

Here's the style declaration:

```
<style name="Theme.MyMine.DropDownNav">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_mymine</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_mymine</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_mymine</item>
</style>
```

Here's the fixed one: I just needed to add a parent. This is the fix for HC+ devices:

```
<style name="Theme.MyMine.DropDownNav"
       parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_mymine</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_mymine</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_mymine</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

NEVER use NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and onNavigationItemSelected it is not worth it !

@Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId)

You also cannot use menu's to do this:

@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

due to inflation ordering. Reasons:

(1) it generates a "hidden" spinner, for which you can not get the id. (2) you cannot customize this spinner (3) you save 30 lines of code, but are permanently limited if you want to add a second bi-directional spinner (4) not even in the special case of "simple code" (one spinner), you lose to much. (5) you cannot use tabs. (6) Why would you not want similar code ?

the key is actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom); and spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()... for each spinner. Trust me I lost hours trying each solution.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Please stop.